# jquery if less than existing data value

Tags: jquery

So, if I have..

```
 <a href="" data-item="14">item 14</a>
 <a href="" data-item="15" class="selected">item 15</a>
 <a href="" data-item="16">item 16</a>
```

and I have 20 of these from 1 - 20.

How can I do a if statement on the one I click on an item that does not have class="selected"?

```
 if i click on 14, then it's less than 15.. do this  
 if i click on 16, it is more than 15.. do this
```

Edited below to explain scenario.

items

```
 <a href="" data-item="14">item 14</a>
 <a href="" data-item="15" class="selected">item 15</a>
 <a href="" data-item="16">item 16</a>
```

if data-item 14 is clicked (which is less than the selected item) - then do this..
if data-item 16 is clicked (which is more than the selected item) - then do this..

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [**`data()`**](http://api.jquery.com/data/) and [**`click()`**](http://api.jquery.com/click/) methods in Jquery as shown below :-

```
$('a[class!="selected"][data-item]').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();  //disable default action 
  var selval = $('a.selected').data('item');
  if(parseInt($(this).data('item')) < parseInt(selval) ){ //use parseint() because you are dealing with numbers here
      //do stuff
   }
  else{
      //do stuff
   }
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/osvksphq/2/)

Comment: while the else does work, i need to know if it is more than or less than the clicked element.

Comment: @venom90.... don't know how someone deleted my previous comment.. above answer will work perfectly in your case added a fiddle link also plz visit that link.. if need more help then comment plz... thanks...

Comment: same as the other, I cannot get the "if" to trigger, the else works fine.  So anything smaller than the current number is not triggering.

Comment: moved some things around, things work now, thanks :)

Comment: @venom90...i have also updated the answer with updated fiddle link as per your updated html markup if you still have some problem then plz refer fiddle.. thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Do it using [**`not()`**](http://api.jquery.com/not/) , [**`data()`**](http://api.jquery.com/data/) and [**`click()`**](http://api.jquery.com/click/) methods in jQuery also add `event.preventDefault()` for prevent default action

```
$("a[data-item]").not(".selected").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault()
     var sel = parseInt($(".selected").data("item"),10);
     if(parseInt($(this).data("item"),10) > sel)
     {
          //do this
     }
     else
     {
          //do this
     }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/jnb7jt8o/)**

Comment: You have 15 hard-coded.  What if I am on another value?

Comment: I cannot get the "if" to trigger, the else works fine.  So anything smaller than the current number is not triggering.

Comment: I believe using    var sel = $(".selected").data("item"); is causing the issue.  Is there a way to say "this data - 1" < this data